# vscode live server extension cuts off JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a online booking system. And I am using vscode live server for live web for testing. I noticed that it cuts off a huge chunk of js code. I am using the newest version of vscode and google chrome. If you need any more information, feel free to ask me :).

Expected Behaviour:

```js
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above
  
    var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
    // var button = document.getElementById("my-form-button");
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
  
    // Success and Error functions for after the form is submitted
  
    function success() {
      form.reset();
      status.classList.add("success");
      status.innerHTML = "Thanks!";
    }
  
    function error() {
      status.classList.add("error");
      status.innerHTML = "Oops! There was a problem.";
    }
  
    // handle the form submission event
  
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = new FormData(form);
      ajax(form.method, form.action, data, success, error);
    });
  });
  
  // helper function for sending an AJAX request
  
  function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      } else {
        error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }
</script>
```

Actual Behavior:

```js
<script>
                window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above
              
                var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
                // var button = document.getElementById("my-form-button");
                var status = document.getElementById("status");
              
                // Success and Error functions for after the form is submitted
              
                function succe</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Reload the webpage and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I have tried that too but it still cut's the script off.